# How to make backup joomla CiviCRM smaller?

Tags: joomla, backups

I made a backup of my `httpdocs` directory (a very small Joomla and CiviCRM extension) and discovered the backup contained more than 15000 different files? Is this normal? can I skip some of these from the backup?.

Thank you
Rob

Answer (score 3):

One great way to shrink the backup is to only backup the bespoke bits (e.g. custom extensions and themes) and the database, not the actual Joomla! and CiviCRM code files that are freely downloaded from elsewhere.

This depends on you not having edited any core files, which your developers shouldn't be doing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the free version of Akeeba Backup lets you exclude directories: https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/405-akeeba-core-vs-professional.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is approximately the number of files. And when you make a code base backup, you have to copy them all. What is the backup method you are using? If your only option is to copy them with (s)ftp transfer this can take a lot of time. But if you have ssh access to the system use zip or tar to pack all these files together, and copy just this single file. And often ISP´s offer faster backup methods in the control panel of the site.

Answer (score 1):

problem was to backup the joomla, civi site because of the huge number of files; so backup with ftp (httpdocs) and database sql with phpmyadmin took several hours

so I tried akeeba free backup, extension for joomla; this works fine and fast on the server itself and I can downlad the akeeba .jpa file (70 MB) also very fast with ftp (downloading over browser is not recommended)

did not try to restore because the site is being used

now I will transfer the site to another subdomain with akeeba, fingers crossed...

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer. It looks like it could be useful to others.  To make it even more helpful you could edit this to provide more details about what you did.  Try to word it so that someone can just read your answer without looking at any of the other answers.  If you can try to answer your original questions.

Answer (score -1):

thank you

I backup the database with phpmyadmin and the files with ftp because then I have the correct versions for joomla and civi

I have no ssh access and never changed the core files so I think of leaving out all unused themes and unused extensions
thnx again